# Trouble setting up systemd service on Centos 7 system

Tags: systemd, services

An application from a vendor was installed with a non-root user. This is supported by the vendor and all is good. So the non-root user owns all the installed application executables and files. One of the software requirements is to set an environment variable in any users profile that will be using the product. In the non-root install only the user that installed it will be using it so I have the following defined in the `.bash_profile`:

```
export CFROOT=/usr/opt/tibco/mft/ps
```

and then I have

```
export PATH=$CFROOT:$PATH
```

and all is well. The user can be logged in and start the daemon and life is good. The user can also log out and the deamon will continue to run.

I want this product to start at bootup to eliminate the need to have to login as this user and start it up.

I created a `mftps.service` file in the `/usr/lib/systemd/system` directory.

The service file contains the following settings:

```
[Unit]
Description=MFT Platform Server Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=tibcomft
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/mftps
ExecStart=/usr/opt/tibco/mft/ps/cfstart
ExecStop=/usr/opt/tibco/mft/ps/cfstop
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Note: Before I added the `EnvironmentFile` I would constantly receive an error that `CFROOT` was not defined. In researching setting this up I found information on this and add the file `/etc/sysconfig/mftps`. In this sysconfig file I have the following:

```
CFROOT=/usr/opt/tibco/mft/ps
export CFROOT
```

Note: The above settings is the only way I have gotten the sysconfig file to work. If I have anything with the "$" in it for instance `export PATH=$CFROOT:$PATH` the `systemctl start` fails.

So what is happening now when I run `systemctl start mftps.service` and then display the status I have see this:

```
[root@centos72sys jbarker]# systemctl status mftps.service
● mftps.service - MFT Platform Server Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mftps.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled) 
 Active: inactive (dead)

Jan 13 13:12:11 centos72sys systemd[1]: Started MFT Platform Server Service.
Jan 13 13:12:11 centos72sys systemd[1]: Starting MFT Platform Server Service...
Jan 13 13:12:11 centos72sys cfstart[4237]: MFT Platform Server Responder will be started from /usr/opt/tibco/mft/ps
Jan 13 13:12:12 centos72sys cfstart[4237]: Failed To Start CyberResp process. Read /usr/opt/tibco/mft/ps/FailureReason.txt
[root@centos72sys jbarker]#
```

When I view the `FailureReason.txt` it states the following:

```
cfsend not found in PATH
```

The `cfsend` executable is in the path that is defined in `$CFROOT` but is nothing that is started when a user runs the `cfstart` command so I don't know why it is throwing this error.

Comment: Why don't you just give this fictional user a proper username instead of calling her `non-root`¿

Comment: The user name is in the details of the mftps.service file. The user is tibcomft. I was simply trying to get across to the readers that the user was not the root user to do the installation of the product.

Comment: Also please indent your log output with 4 spaces so it becomes a code block. This is horrible to read on a phone.

Comment: You can write a wrapper to start the program and put that as the shell of the user (preferably in C,  not an interpreted language, such an account can be broken into)

Comment: I am open to ideas and the writing of a wrapper is definitely something I can look in to, do you have any links I can read on the subject of writing wrappers that you have found to be good?

Comment: I was able to finally get this working. I made a few changes to the various files I had entered details for from the original setup. I created a startup script /usr/bin/mftps. I have the following details in it: '#!/bin/sh
 
export CFROOT=/usr/opt/tibco/mft/ps
export PATH=$CFROOT:$PATH
 
start(){
/usr/opt/tibco/mft/ps/./cfstart
}
 
stop(){
/usr/opt/tibco/mft/ps/./cfstop
}
 
case $1 in
start|stop) "$1" ;;
esac'

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and it resolved by adding below lines in /etc/sysconfig/mftps

```
more /etc/sysconfig/mftps
CFROOT=/apps/opt/mftps
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/root/bin:/apps/opt/mftps:/apps/opt/mftps/config

more /etc/systemd/system/mftps.service
[Unit]
Description=MFT Platform Server Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=root
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/mftps
ExecStart=/apps/opt/mftps/cfstart
ExecStop=/apps/opt/mftps/cfstop
RemainAfterExit=yes
WorkingDirectory=/apps/opt/mftps

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

ps -ef | grep Cyb
root     22513     1  0 13:22 ?        00:00:00 /apps/opt/mftps/CyberResp
root     22731 20313  0 13:23 pts/18   00:00:00 grep --color=auto Cyb

systemctl stop mftps.service

ps -ef | grep Cyb
root     25374 20313  0 13:25 pts/18   00:00:00 grep --color=auto Cyb

systemctl start mftps.service
ps -ef | grep Cyb
root     26454     1  0 13:25 ?        00:00:00 /apps/opt/mftps/CyberResp
root     26698 20313  0 13:25 pts/18   00:00:00 grep --color=auto Cyb
```